# Can not access Internet on N9100 Android 4.4.2

Tags: wi-fi, sim-card

I bought  a smartphone (N9100) which is running Android version 4.4.2 (kernel version: 3.4.67).

When I plugged the SIM card in the smartphone, I set Data connection to the name of the company that provided it to me.

I went to `Settings` -> `WIRELESS & NETWORKS`  and set `Wi-FI` to `ON`

I see now : ***3G h+***(with three vertical bars).

I open the browser and type any page but it says I have no connection.

Also, when I check in `Wi-Fi` -> `Advanced` , I see that I have no IPv4 address assigned to me.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: WiFi has nothing at all to do with the SIM card. Can you see the company's WiFi network name in *Settings › WiFi*? If so, tap it and provide the network key. It then should connect to this WiFi network.

Comment: Now you're talking about *mobile data* – and yes, *that's* connected to the SIM (other than WiFi). Usually, when plugging in a SIM Android tries to automatically configure the network corresponding to your provider. If your provider is relatively unknown, that might fail. You will need to check the [APN settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/apn/info) then. If no APN is configured, contact your provider for details; they might send you a service-SMS for auto-configuration.

Comment: OK, with that verified, time to [check the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) – something's going wrong here, so the logs should give at least a pointer to what that might be.

Comment: sorry for a stupid sounding question. But have you actually turned on your mobile data switch? From the question you were mixing things up when your were asking. So you could just have not turned on your mobile data switch.

Comment: This questions needs to have a better description - please rephrase your original question with the newest information - include which service provider your sim card is from, include screen shots from the APN settings. Otherwise we can only guess but can't help you that much.

Comment: Turn off wifi (and vpn , firewalls if any). Turn on mobile data. Restart phone.

Comment: *Mobile data* means  mobile internet(2G, 3G, etc ). It can be toggled from the notification area.

Comment: @Begueradj So did you get it to work?? Your comment was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @Manubhargav convert your comment into an answer and I will accept (APN settings were the problem)

Comment: @Manubhargav yes, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior (*3G/H/H+ shows up in notification bar, but no internet connection*) usually occurs when APN settings are not configured properly.Also since it's a new phone, recently purchased you might need to configure APN settings pertaining to your network carrier (*service provider*)

APN settings can be obtained by calling up the customer support,asking them to send the APN setting through message(*sms*) or by googling even.

[Some](https://support.t-mobile.com/message/473746) have found a workaround for the issue by simply changing preferred network type to *2G only*

Also working on mobile data(2G/3G) does not assign any IPV4 under WiFi settings because that section shows IPV4 address assigned only by WiFi connections.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>